# Toggle button with value from sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small toggle button, and I store value (true or false) to sessionStorage, and on page load, if the value exists in sessionStorage I take it and show toggle button depending on value, also, depending on this value I show different content on my angularjs page.

Problem is, I store a value to sessionStorage, and on again I call this value but my toggle button and my ng-if statement do not get this. Here is my code bellow.

Question is, how, and why I can't get this to the ng-if statement? (in my fiddle I use ng-show because ng-if not working in this example)

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k73sLfvp/1/)

```js
var app = angular.module("ap", []);

app.controller("con", function($scope) {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("modePreview")) {
    $scope.basicMode = sessionStorage.getItem("modePreview");
  } else {
    $scope.basicMode = true;
  }
  $scope.sendModeValueToStorage = function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem(
      "modePreview",
      ($scope.basicMode = !$scope.basicMode)
    );
  };

});
```

```css
.activeSwitch,
.inactiveSwitch {
  font-size: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

i.activeSwitch {
  color: #e4e4e471;
}

i.inactiveSwitch {
  color: #e4e4e471;
}

.fontStyleUserControlPannel {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body ng-app="ap" ng-controller="con">

  Advanced mode <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x" ng-click="sendModeValueToStorage()" ng-class="{'fa-rotate-180' : basicMode}"></i> Basic mod

  <div ng-show="!basicMode">
    <h3>
      Basic mode
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="basicMode">
    <h3>
      Advanced mode
    </h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

First, in your fiddle, you're using AngularJS version 1.1.1. `ng-if` did not exist in AngularJS prior to version 1.1.5. So you'll want to update your AngularJS version to use `ng-if`.

Secondly, `sessionStorage` can only accept string values. So if you want to store a JS object in `sessionStorage`, you have to `JSON.stringify()` the object to store it, and use `JSON.parse()` when retrieving it.

Finally, your conditional block always sets `$scope.basicMode` to `true`:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("modePreview")) { // if modePreview is true
  $scope.basicMode = sessionStorage.getItem("modePreview"); // set basicMode to true
} else { // otherwise, still set basicMode to true?
  $scope.basicMode = true;
}
```

I think you want the `else` statement to be `$scope.basicMode = false`, right?

Updated Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zx02f1yv/

Comment: thnx, I updated. Do you know why i can't get value from session storage to ng-if?

Comment: Thank you, I can not believe I predicted this. I've been doing  a hundred times with sessionStorage. i think its Time to leave office for this week :D :D

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)